# How to convert this column into 12h format?

Tags: python, pandas, database, numpy

I have imported a dataset into a Pandas dataframe, but I can't quite figure out how I could convert the start time to a 12h clock (e.g. 4 pm)?

The variable columns are as follows:

| start |
| --- |
| 2022-01-01 00:07:52.943 |
| 2022-01-01 00:09:31.745 |
| 2022-01-01 00:14:37.187 |

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide your data as reproducible text (or DataFrame constructor). Images are not acceptable.

Comment: I think this is a bit of an X-Y question – why do you need 12h dates? That'd be purely a display/formatting thing.

Comment: Well based on the start times, I want to develop a user-defined function that will print the hour, expressed in the 12-hour clock format (e.g., 12am, 1pm), whereby the highest number of commuters start their journey.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
df['start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start'])
df['start'] = df['start'].dt.date.astype(str) + ' ' + df['start'].dt.strftime('%I:%M %p')
```

`OUTPUT`

```
                 start
0  2022-01-01 12:07 AM
1  2022-01-01 12:09 AM
2  2022-01-01 12:14 AM
```

Comment: Thank you! Now based on the start times in the right format, I want to develop a user-defined function that will print the hour, expressed in the 12-hour clock format (e.g., 12am, 1pm), whereby the highest number of commuters start their journey. How could I do so? I tried `x = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='60Min'))
display(x)` but it throws an error

Answer (score 0):

**If dates are datetime values:**

```
df.start.dt.strftime('%H%P')
```